How many "special characters" are there in the ASCII character set?
Website passwords often require at least one character from each of the following classes of character:


Big uppercase letters (ABC...WXYZ)
Small lowercase letters (abc...wxyz)
Numbers (0123456789)
Special characters


The question is, just how many special characters are there?

Why would someone want to know?Why would we care how many special characters there are?
Many users read error message explaining that the password they chose is insecure because the password does not contain a special character, or it does not contain upper-case letter, etc...
An end-user's experience is improved upon when the end-user does not have to read as many error messages as they used to.
Instead of using the rule that at least one character from each category must be in the password, we can allow passwords to use letters only, but use a different function to compute the maximum number of guesses required to guess all passwords that are similar to that password.
A reasonable password security rating is shown below, but the number of special characters (x) is missing from the mathematical formula.
Suppose that nchars is the  number of characters inside of the password.That is, nchars is the length of the password.



ContainsSmallLowercaseLetter(s)
ContainsLargeUppercaseLetter(s)
ContainsNumber(s)
ContainsSpecialCharacter(s)
formula




No
No
No
No
1 = 0^(nchars)


No
No
No
yes
(x)^(nchars)


No
No
yes
no
(10)^(nchars)


No
No
yes
yes
(10+x)^(nchars)


No
yes
No
no
(26)^(nchars)


No
yes
No
yes
(26+x)^(nchars)


No
yes
yes
no
(36)^(nchars)


No
yes
yes
yes
(36+x)^(nchars)


yes
No
No
No
26^(nchars)


yes
No
No
yes
(26+x)^(nchars)


yes
No
yes
no
(36)^(nchars)


yes
No
yes
yes
(36+x)^(nchars)


yes
yes
No
no
(52)^(nchars)


yes
yes
No
yes
(52+x)^(nchars)


yes
yes
yes
no
(62)^(nchars)


yes
yes
yes
yes
(62+x)^(nchars)




I’m voting to close this question because it does not involve a detailed practical problem with using a specific web application. To learn the basics of this site, please read the [tour].

The answer is that there are 31 special characters for passwords if a password only allows ASCII symbols.
A password only allows ASCII symbols if passwords have no Arabic, no Japanese, no Korean, et cetera.
The special characters are…

straight-double-quote "



backslash \



The following:

!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}

